# J2ME Integer to Hex String

Tags: mobile, java-me

I need to convert from an integer to a hexadecimal string (Character string) in Java ME (v3.2). I tried to try String.format() but that is not supported in this version. Any other alternatives?
Sample code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Integer.toHexString](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString(int)).

Comment: This is what I get 
_The primitive type int of i does not have a field toHexString_ Neither does my platform support JSR118

Comment: Is this how you did? int i = 10; String s = Integer.toHexString(i);

Comment: I did not do it like that. Works fine now! Thank you @Telmo

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I implement the following in J2ME? 'List<ObjectItem>'

Comment: You can create your own... "class ObjectItemList extends AbstractList"